# Solaris 10 Memory Size different from Physical Memory Size

Tags: unix, memory, solaris, solaris-10

Why is this? I am not using any zones (global only), so memory capping doesn't seem to be the answer and all the DIMM modules show as enabled with no faults when digging into this from the ILOM.

```
root@alfred:/root# prtdiag
System Configuration:  Oracle Corporation  sun4v Sun Blade T6320 Server Module G2
Memory size: 2048 Megabytes

================================ Virtual CPUs ================================


CPU ID Frequency Implementation         Status
------ --------- ---------------------- -------
0      1415 MHz  SUNW,UltraSPARC-T2     on-line
1      1415 MHz  SUNW,UltraSPARC-T2     on-line
2      1415 MHz  SUNW,UltraSPARC-T2     on-line
3      1415 MHz  SUNW,UltraSPARC-T2     on-line
4      1415 MHz  SUNW,UltraSPARC-T2     on-line
5      1415 MHz  SUNW,UltraSPARC-T2     on-line
6      1415 MHz  SUNW,UltraSPARC-T2     on-line
7      1415 MHz  SUNW,UltraSPARC-T2     on-line

======================= Physical Memory Configuration ========================
Segment Table:
--------------------------------------------------------------
Base           Segment  Interleave   Bank     Contains
Address        Size     Factor       Size     Modules
--------------------------------------------------------------
0x0            32 GB    8            4 GB     MB/CMP0/BR0/CH0/D0
                                              MB/CMP0/BR0/CH1/D0
                                     4 GB     MB/CMP0/BR0/CH0/D1
                                              MB/CMP0/BR0/CH1/D1
                                     4 GB     MB/CMP0/BR1/CH0/D0
                                              MB/CMP0/BR1/CH1/D0
                                     4 GB     MB/CMP0/BR1/CH0/D1
                                              MB/CMP0/BR1/CH1/D1
                                     4 GB     MB/CMP0/BR2/CH0/D0
                                              MB/CMP0/BR2/CH1/D0
                                     4 GB     MB/CMP0/BR2/CH0/D1
                                              MB/CMP0/BR2/CH1/D1
                                     4 GB     MB/CMP0/BR3/CH0/D0
                                              MB/CMP0/BR3/CH1/D0
                                     4 GB     MB/CMP0/BR3/CH0/D1
                                              MB/CMP0/BR3/CH1/D1
```

Comment: Post the contents of `/etc/system`.  Are there any `physmem` entries in it?  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-0404/chapter2-2/index.html  Also post the output from the `fmadm faulty` command.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1451/glisy.html

Comment: `grep physmem /etc/system` yields no output and so does `fmadm faulty`. In fact, it looks like every line in /etc/system has a `*` at the beginning, which I assume means the whole thing is commented. Please let me know if you still want it posted.

Comment: OK, what's the output from `lgrpinfo`?

Comment: I do not have that command on this machine...

Comment: What version of Solaris do you have installed?  What's the output from `uname -a` and the contents of `/etc/release`?

Comment: Post the output of "virtinfo -a". You sure you're not looking at a primary ldom - you're on a T2 host which has SparcVM capability. "ldm ls" might also provide some useful info.

Comment: root@alfred:/root# cat /etc/release  
`Oracle Solaris 10 1/13 s10s_u11wos_24a SPARC  
Copyright (c) 1983, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved. Assembled 17 January 2013`

Comment: root@alfred:/root# uname -a
`SunOS alfred 5.10 Generic_150400-42 sun4v sparc SUNW,Sun-Blade-T6320`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're on an ldom, likely a primary.

Post the output of "virtinfo -a". You're on a T6320 host which has SparcVM capability.

"ldm ls" and "ldm ls-spconfig" might also provide some useful info.

Comment: no ldm... root@alfred:/root# virtinfo -a
Domain role: LDoms control I/O service root  
Domain name: primary  
Domain UUID: c58a9712-8aa1-40cf-fb61-9ed6fa814c41  
Control domain: alfred  
Chassis serial#: 0111APO-0932YG03E8

Comment: Absolutely LDM. You have a primary domain controller with IO services available.

Comment: From memory "ldm -V"  should get you the version of sparc VM you are using, I suggest you read the manual from the Oracle support website. Try *sparc vm administration guide* ini your favourite search engine and work from there. You also failed to post output of _ldm ls_ and _ldm ls-spconfig_ - please do so.

Comment: I'm not using a VM........root@alfred:/root# ldm -V
`-bash: ldm: command not found`

Comment: virtinfo says you are. Check your $PATH.